# LocationClient not connected although onConnected was called

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

In my application I'm trying to use the LocationService based on Google's tutorial "Retrieving the Current Location" (http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).
Unfortunately when I actually need it I get a **'IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected'** exception.
I need the location service for a very short period - on pressing
some button I want to get the current location (or last known location).
My LocationHandler code is as follows:

```
class LocationHandler implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
                                GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private MainActivity m_ma;
    private LocationClient m_locationClient;
    private boolean m_isAvailable = false;


    //ctor
    LocationHandler(MainActivity ma) {
        m_ma = ma;
        m_locationClient = new LocationClient(ma, this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(m_ma, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        m_isAvailable = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "LOCATION = " + m_locationClient.getLastLocation());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(m_ma, "Disconnected."
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        m_isAvailable = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "LOCATION dis-connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        m_isAvailable = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "LOCATION failed");
        ... code from tutorial
    }

    //connect the LocationClient
    void connectLocationClient() {
        m_locationClient.connect();
    }

    //disconnect the LocationClient
    void diconnectLocationClient() {
        m_locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    //
    Location getCurrentLocation() {
        connectLocationClient();
        if(m_isAvailable) {
            Log.i(TAG, "3333333333333333 m_locationClient.isConnected() = " + m_locationClient.isConnected());
            return m_locationClient.getLastLocation();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "444444444444");
            Toast.makeText(m_ma, "Location Services is not yet avaialable",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The button's onClick code calls the `getCurrentLocation()` method.
On the first click I obviously get a null Location and the "... not yet available" Toast.
Then `onConnected(..)` callback is invoked and `getLastLocation()` inside it succeeds.
Then when I press again on the button I get the `IllegalStateException` since the LocationClient
is not connected.
How come it is not connected if I already seen that `onConnected()` was invoked, but didn't seen neither `onDisconnected()` nor `onConnectionFailed(..)` being called?